# Inlining template in Catalyst/TT

Tags: perl, catalyst

I was wondering whether anyone knows how to inline templates in the DATA section of a module in Catalyst (I'd like to use Template Toolkit) like it seems possible in Mojolicious, where you can do things like this (from the documentation):

```
# /bar
get '/bar' => sub {
     my $self = shift;
     $self->stash(one => 23);
     $self->render('baz', two => 24);
};

__DATA__

@@ baz.html.ep
The magic numbers are <%= $one %> and <%= $two %>.
```

It makes for easier maintenance as I code, though I might move everything to a separate file later.

Thanks,

Simone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of concept:

```
package Foo::Bar::Controller::Root;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller' }
use Inline::Files;
use Template;
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');
sub end :ActionClass('RenderView') {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    my $in = readline $c->stash->{template};
    my $tt = Template->new;
    my $out;
    $tt->process(\$in, $c->stash, \$out) or die $tt->error;
    $c->response->body($out);
}
sub bar :Path {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->stash(template => 'BAZ', one => 23, two => 24);
}
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

__END__

__BAZ__
The magic numbers are [% one %] and [% two %].
```

It works, but I can't recommend it. It is an egregious violation of the MVC principles Catalyst is built on.

Comment: I don't think it's an abuse of MVC principles as such.  On the other hand I don't think it's a particularly great idea either :)  Early on/small project hack, yes.  As a standard way to do things, not so great.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've also tried out Data::Section::Simple in the meantime. And I agree - after trying it out - it's great in the early phases of trying out things, but I wouldn't want to keep it that way for any template that's longer than 10 lines.